# How to expose ReadOnly property in my WPF control?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control with a dependency property.
I want the users of my control to be able to bind a Property, so they can use the value in their ViewModel, but I don't want them to be able to change it.
Since ReadOnly Dependency Properties are not bindeable, how can I do this?

Comment: You can't.  Attaching a `Binding` sets the property, and there is no way to distinguish between setting the property via a `Binding` and setting it via some other method, e.g., `SetValue`.  You could do some funky analysis via a property changed callback to see if the property is data-bound, and if not, reject the value, but that strikes me as terrible design.

Comment: Could users of your control not declare their DependencyObject implementation, which uses your control as a _source_ for their DO? Then you could publish the property changes via INotifyPropertyChanged and allow binding to the client's DO? They could then map the value back to their own code however they like, without the opportunity to change the value in your own control.

Comment: @MikeStrobel most workarounds I have seen for this strike me as terrible also. People use a normal property and throw an exception on the Set method, etc. That is why I am asking what is the best way to resolve this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I suppose they could, but isn't there really any other way? I am trying to minimize the amount of work my users will have to do.